# how to create a background task in spring to keep listening to data on TCP socket

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

On webapp start, it should connect to the socket and keep listening to events on the socket until the lifecycle of the webapp (forever, until of course tomcat is killed).

I have been searching for quite some time, but background tasks just return after their execution is done, but I want the thread to be alive to receive incoming data on the socket.

Any help ?

Comment: Show some code. It is hard to tell what is problem in code without seeing it.

Comment: @Meraman I dont know how to proceed and what to code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the socket handler in `ContextListener` and then it'll be a part of the `Main thread` and won't die unless the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Spring? If so, you may want to take a look at Spring Integration project: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html. I think it will be the best tool for your current problem.

Comment: Then explain exactly what you want :) Should your application open a server TCP socket and listen for events? What is the message format being sent over the wire?